# is using ng-model is inefficient?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple use case in my application. when user double click on a record it will show an input box and after submitting new text and hit enter. that will update the record.

all I want to do is grab input elements value and fire service.

```
<input  type="text" ng-model="updatedListTitle" ng-enter="updateList(list.id, updatedListTitle)">
```

as you can see I am using ngmodel to grab data in my controller. the problem is with every keystroke it is firing all my watchers unnecessarily (even though i know angular is fast and you can fire like 1000 watcher and all ). but just grabbing the element using jquery would be more efficient.

is there any better approach to handle these situation where i really don't care about 2 way binding

Answer (score 0):

Well..., in my opinion the way you have done it is perfectly idiomatic angularjs and I wouldn't start to micro-optimize it.
(Remember "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" as well as Michael A. Jacksons rules about optimization and other quotes - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization )

No, I don't think there is any sensible way to do it without jQuery (or at least jqLite or manual dom access). 
If you do that, you should encapsulate it in a directive (which arguably is the only place explicit DOM access/manipulation should be).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ng-blur here instead of ng-enter and then check to see if the model is dirty and then do the service call?

AngularJS sets the CSS classes ng-pristine and ng-dirty on any input field you've used ng-model on, and your controller has the properties $pristine and $dirty which you can check to see if the form is dirty or not.

That might be a bit more optimized.  I would still do this in a directive though.